# Set firefox profile protractor

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver, firefox-profile

I try to use this code:

```
var makeFirefoxProfile = function (preferenceMap) {
  var deferred = q.defer();
  var firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();

  for (var key in preferenceMap) {
    firefoxProfile.setPreference(key, preferenceMap[key]);
  }

  firefoxProfile.encoded(function (encodedProfile) {
    var capabilities = {
      browserName: "firefox",
      firefox_profile: encodedProfile
    };

    deferred.resolve(capabilities);
  });
  return deferred.promise;
};

  getMultiCapabilities: function () {
    return q.all([
      makeFirefoxProfile(
        {
          "browser.download.folderList": 2,
          "browser.download.dir": "D:/Automation",
          "browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force": false
        }
      )
    ]);
  },
```

But it show error: 
**Error: TypeError: profile.getTemplateDir is not a function**
I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: What Protractor, Firefox, q, firefox-profile versions do you use? Trying to reproduce the problem but works for me so far (I have an exact same `makeFirefoxProfile` function)

Comment: Protractor 5.0
Firefox 51.0.1 (64 bit) 
"firefox-profile": "^0.4.8",

Comment: Can you support for me? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried executing `webdriver-manager update` and then trying running protractor again?

Comment: Hi, I have wonder that  profile = caps.get(Capability.PROFILE); is string, and   getTemplateDir() {return this.template_;} is in class Profile????

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it seems like `selenium-webdriver` (which is used by `protractor`) used to accept a base64 encoded string `firefox_profile` capability property. But now it expects a `selenium-webdriver/firefox`.`Profile` instance. So here is how you can solve your issue:

```
// make sure you have access to the selenium-webdriver firefox Profile class
var FirefoxProfile = require("selenium-webdriver/firefox").Profile;
//... 
// then change makeFirefoxProfile() function implementation with the following...

var makeFirefoxProfile = function (preferenceMap) {
  var profile = new FirefoxProfile();
  for (var key in preferenceMap) {
    profile.setPreference(key, preferenceMap[key]);
  }
  return q.resolve({
    browserName: "firefox",
    marionette: true,
    firefox_profile: profile
  });
};
```

I hope this helps.

Note that `firefox-profile` package is no longer needed.