# WebDriverError: Invalid Firefox preference value: network.http.phishy-userpass-length=255

Tags: javascript, firefox, selenium-webdriver, protractor, geckodriver

I'm trying to start a new test case via gecko driver (v0.15) with specific Firefox profile in Protractor 5.1.1. Following description was used to create the profile: [Set firefox profile protractor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42151372/error-typeerror-profile-gettemplatedir-is-not-a-function-when-set-firefox-prof)

When I start the execution via protractor configuration, I get following error:

> WebDriverError: Invalid Firefox preference value: network.http.phishy-userpass-length=255

The same behavior for the preference `browser.download.folderList` reference.

```
firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2);
```

Is there a workaround for this settings? I get a blocking popup, if the phishy-userpass-length is not set.

Thanks!

Regards,
Waldemar

Answer (score 0):

This hidden preference key [`network.http.phishy-userpass-length`](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Network.http.phishy-userpass-length) is not created by default in Firefox profile.

Have you also invoked `fb.updatePreferences();` visible at https://www.npmjs.com/package/firefox-profile ?

According to [this old issue](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=243572#c3), you have to add it manually in `about:config` thanks to a right click and New->Integer.

Comment: I added the flag in about:config already... without success, still the same error. According to this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42151372/error-typeerror-profile-gettemplatedir-is-not-a-function-when-set-firefox-prof), firefox-profile no longer needed: "Note that firefox-profile package is no longer needed."