# Error : profile.getTemplateDir is not a function

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I'm trying to implement a multi-browser test with protractor with firefox and chrome. But for the test, I need to change the download path. In chrome, it works but in firefox, the solution I found involved changing the profile of firefox. I also found a way to do it as in the answers of this question [Set firefox profile protractor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42151372/set-firefox-profile-protractor) .

But when I try to run multiple instance of navigator alongside of one instance of firefox with modified profile, I always get an error as `profile.getTemplateDir is not a function`.

Here is the code in my protractor configuration file :

```
var q = require('q');
var FirefoxProfile = require("selenium-webdriver/firefox").Profile   

function getProfiles() {
  let deferred = q.defer();

  let multiCapabilities = [{
    browserName: 'chrome'
  }]
  deferred.resolve(multiCapabilities);
  let firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
  firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2);
  firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", false);
  firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.dir", '/tmp'); 

  let foxCapabilities = {
    browserName: 'firefox',
    firefox_profile: firefoxProfile
  };
  multiCapabilities.push(foxCapabilities);

  deferred.resolve(multiCapabilities);
  return deferred.promise;
}

exports.config = {
  seleniumAddress: "http://localhost:4444/wd/hub",
  specs: [
    'spec.js'
  ],
  framework: 'jasmine2',
  getMultiCapabilities: getProfiles,
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000
  },
};
```

Does anyone knows why this error is triggered and how to resolve it ?

Thanks

Comment: I think your issue is that the profile is being created once and reused by the framework

Comment: This code works for one instance of firefox, but if I try to add for example another instance of chrome or firefox browser, then the error gets triggered

Comment: Yes, because the code is not generating a fresh profile object on the second invocation. you need to debug that.

Comment: I already tried to debug for days, literally, that's why I post it here. And I don't invoke twice the profile, I'm running browsers at the same time (firefox+chrome for example) while the firefox has a changed profile.

Comment: Create a sample git repo to recreate the issue, I will give it a shot

Comment: Here is the repo [https://github.com/nirinapf/protractor-firefox-customized-profile](https://github.com/nirinapf/protractor-firefox-customized-profile) . Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I have digged into this issue debugging the code and this seems to be limitation/bug currently in selenium web-driver

When `getMultiCapabilities` returns multiple browsers, then protractor creates a fork of the process to run the test

[image: Fork Process]

This forked process is then sent the profile you created as JSON

[image: ChildProcess Send]

The childprocess can only receive JSON data in form of text and not in form of a `Profile` object

[image: Child Process Jsonify]

Later `createGeckodriver` function is called with profile object. But as the code of `createGeckodriver` it is always expecting a profile object

[image: Create GeckoDriver profile]

So this code needs to be fixed in Selenium webdriver itself and it should check if the profile sent is already encoded or not.  Also the code you have used needs to be fixed to encode the profile. Below is what would work once Selenium driver is patched to allow sending encoded profile

```
var firefox = require('selenium-webdriver/firefox');
var q = require('q');
var FirefoxProfile = require("selenium-webdriver/firefox").Profile

var makeFirefoxProfile = function (preferenceMap) {
    var deferred = q.defer();
    var firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
    for (var key in preferenceMap) {
        firefoxProfile.setPreference(key, preferenceMap[key]);
    }

    firefoxProfile.encode().then(function(encodedProfile){
        cap =  {
            "browserName": "firefox",
            marionette: true,
            "firefox_profile": encodedProfile,
        };

        deferred.resolve(cap);
    });

    return deferred.promise;
};

exports.config = {
    seleniumAddress: "http://localhost:4444/wd/hub",
    specs: [
        'spec.js'
    ],
    framework: 'jasmine',
    getMultiCapabilities: function () {
        return q.all([
            {
                browserName: 'chrome'
            },

            makeFirefoxProfile(
                {
                    "browser.download.folderList": 2,
                    "browser.download.dir": "/path/to/save/downloads",
                    "browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk": "application/zip"
                }
            )
        ]);
    },
    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 180000
    }
};
```

Comment: Running into the same issue - thanks for your investigation! I just wondered which versions of protractor and selenium-webdriver you were using, and if it's been fixed yet?

Comment: Thanks! I have problems with it since a couple of weeks and I solved adapting my code with this snippet!